# Angular -Material Table - not displaying data instantly

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Mitarbeiter>(); 
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadMitarbeiterEbene1();
  }


loadMitarbeiterEbene1(): void {
    this.mitarbeiterService.getMitarbeiterEbene1().subscribe(mitarbeiter => {
      if (mitarbeiter) {
        this.dataSource.data = mitarbeiter;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
    });
  }
```

```
    let emailsListe: Observable<{ employees: string[] }>;
    let mitarbeiterListe: Mitarbeiter[] = [];
    return new Observable<Mitarbeiter[]>(observer => {
      // email Liste auf der ersten Ebene bestimmen
      emailsListe = this.httpClient
        .get<{ employees: string[] }>('HERE_IS_MY_URL', {
          headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer myToken')
        })
        .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));

      emailsListe.subscribe(data => {
        data.employees.forEach(value => {
          this.httpClient
            .get<any>(`HERE_IS_MY_URL`, {
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer myToken')
            })
            .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError))
            .subscribe(data => {
              let localMitarbeier: Mitarbeiter = new Mitarbeiter(data.sn, data.givenName);

              mitarbeiterListe.push(localMitarbeier);
            });
        });
      });
      observer.next(mitarbeiterListe);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
```

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Hello guys, i have a weird problem.

I am getting the data for my Datasource as an Observable<Mitarbeiter[]> through my mitarbeiterService... I am able to set the data and if I do a console log after subscribing to the observable I am able to see the data.

Somehow when my application loads, the data is not visible. Only after a click on some column, or on the table in general the data appears in the table but neve directly after loading the page.

I tried to use ngOnInit() instead of AfterViewInit() but there I have the same problem, and the paginator/sort does not work.

Comment: That might be some weird issue. If `dataSource.data` is an array of objects, you can try `this.dataSource.data = [...mitarbeiter]`. Also, try initializing `dataSource` with some value, to see if that value gets displayed in the table (or at least add an object with empty values). I'm just saying what I first thought of, haven't tested.

Comment: I suspect you're having a problem with your nested subscribes. If you sort those out, it should work ok. In the meantime, try throwing a `delay(0)` in one of your pipes. It's like a `setTimeout` of zero, it pushes execution onto the next event loop. Or something like that, JS is weird.

Comment: The nested subscribes were the reason. After i changed it a little bit it worked.